# JavaScript CSS Selection based on current Browser's Width and Height

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, browser-detection

I am trying to create a JavaScript that detects the browser resolution, and based on the browser resolution a comparison statement selects the most appropriate CSS for the page reload. I know its easier to use percentages, but for what this project contains this can not be done. So I am stuck writing something basic, and can't seem to find the error for some  reason...

Everything works smoothly up to the point of the comparison statement.

Here is the script:

```
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function smallTest() {
  var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    //Non-IE
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ||     document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
   myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 4 compatible
    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }
}

if ((myWidth == 1280) && (myHeight == 768))
       {document.write("<link href='css/Foo.1280.800.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");} 
   
        else if (( myWidth == 800) && ( myHeight == 600))      
         { document.write("<link href='css/Foo.1024.768.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
     
        else if (( myWidth == 1024) && ( myHeight == 768))      
         { document.write("<link href='css/Foo.1024.768.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
     
        else if ( (myWidth == 1280) && ( myHeight == 1040))      
          {document.write("<link href='css/Foo.1280.1040.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
     
        else if (( myWidthh == 1600) && ( myHeight == 900))      
          {document.write("<link href='css/Foo.1600.900.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
             
    else if (( myWidth == 1920) && ( myHeight == 1080))      
          {document.write("<link href='css/Foo.1920.1080.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
     
    else if ( (myWidth == 1920) && ( myHeight == 1200))      
          { document.write("<link href='css/Foo.1920.1200.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}

</script>
<body window.onload="smallTest()">
```

Comment: The condition is somehow preventing a CSS from loading. idk y

Comment: This is a job for media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Don't check for exact sizes. Everyone's browser window is going to be a different size and you're not likely to get too many users who are at an exact match for your css.

Do relative comparisons instead:

```
if (width < 800) && (height < 600) {
      use "microscopic" page layout
} else {
    ....
}
```

You COULD check for the actual screen resolution, using `screen.width` and `screen.height`, but again, not everyone will have a standard-sized screen. If they're running inside a VM, their screen resolution may the size of the window the VM's displaying inside of, which is not likely to be an exact match to a standard screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing window size with screen resolution.  What you're getting is the resolution of the ***window***, but you're trying to compare it to the resolution of the ***screen***, which will never match.

`window.screen` has information about the screen resolution if you happen to want that, but I would strongly recommend against using it, and instead just doing looser conditions:

```
if((myWidth >= 800) && (myWidth >= 600)){
   ...
}else if((myWidth >= 1024) && (myHeight >= 768)){
   ...
}
```

Although since those numbers are based on ***screen*** resolution, the height will always be less and the width will almost always be less, so you may be better off with just:

```
if(myWidth >= 750){
    ...
}else if(myWidth >= 950){
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am using the window resolution. So when people resize the browser window it should change the webpage to better suit their working environment. I am using a Mozilla browser, and it still doesn't work for some reason. It works when I use just document.write for the css, but when I add a condition it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script solution:

Description: determines the browsers width and height, and based on the resolution it provides a CSS script that will meet it's needs th best. Great for information displaying purposes requiring exact sizes for monitors in use.

```
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) 
{
winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 winW = window.innerWidth;
winH = window.innerHeight;
}

if ( winW < 801)      
     { document.write("<link href='css/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}

    else if (( winW <= 1024) && ( winW > 801))      
     { 
        if (winH >= 768)
        {document.write("<link href='css/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
        else if (winH < 768)
        {document.write("<link href='css/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
     }

    else if ((winW <= 1280) && (winW > 1024))
     { 
        if (winH >=801)
     {document.write("<link href='css/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
        else if (winH < 801)
        {document.write("<link href='css/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
     }

    else if (( winW <= 1600) && ( winW > 1280))
     { 
        if (winH >=900)
     {document.write("<link href='css/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
        else if (winH < 900)
        {document.write("<link href='css/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
     }      

    else if ( winW > 1600)     
     { 
        if (winH >=1200)
     {document.write("<link href='css/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
        else if (winH < 1200)
        {document.write("<link href='css/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");}
     }
```